# does anyone know why facebook puts the wrong picture

Tags: android, facebook, share, image

I have this code for sharing an app on facebook but when i share it it puts right links but wrong picture of the app

```
Button bShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    bShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myglobaljournal.christmascarol");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myglobaljournal.christmascarol) to check how facebook "sees" this url.

From the result you can see that there are no og meta tags defined and so facebook probably takes a random picture from the content.

---

## Edit

Facebook uses the open graph meta tags to extract info which is then used to render the share stories on the facebook experience.

You can see an example in the [archived version of the Open Graph protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/), the new version uses the tags there but it's too complicated to your needs.

The only question is: can you any control over the output of the google play store for your app?
My guess is that you can't, and if you look at other examples (such as [instagram](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android) or [opera mobile](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser)) the image also appears random.

Comment: You'll need to somehow make sure that the html output has the `og:image` meta tag, do you have any control over the output?

Comment: first thank you for anwsering me i dont know where my manners where haha i was exited to hear someone know what i was talking about, i am new to programing and so far i enjoy it a lot haha even the headaches, it is an aplication am building but i dont understand where i should place the meta tag?

Comment: You can't fix this if the content comes from a site you don't manage (for example, Google Play).

Comment: oh :( is there any way around it ?

Comment: the only thing i can think of is i have a developers acount where i put the picture of the app would that help any?

Comment: I have no idea. You can try and check, but since apps like instagram don't have their own image I doubt that it's possible.

Comment: oh and what about if i created a webpage with content that will automatically redirect the link to the google play website would that work cuz then i would have access to creating a meta tag

Comment: @user1385487 Have you finally tried creating a page that contains the appropriate meta tag and redirects to Google Play ?

Comment: I did and it works but the thing is that android doesnt launch correctly then so i decided to let it be :), thanks for asking